# What does quote in select is intended to do?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am stuck on a select I saw in production code which looks similar to this one and is a part of a PL/SQL procedure (rest of it I consider as irrelevant):

```
SELECT 'Tag1' FIELD_ONE, 'English' FIELD_TWO, 'DummyData' FIELD_THREE FROM SOME_TABLE;
```

What are these quotes intended to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that you didn't select those values from columns but as "constants". For example:

```
SQL> SELECT 'Tag1' FIELD_ONE, 'English' FIELD_TWO, 'DummyData' FIELD_THREE FROM dual;

FIEL FIELD_T FIELD_THR
---- ------- ---------
Tag1 English DummyData

SQL>
```

Comment: So it will give me following row as many times as there are rows in DUAL regardless of DUAL table's column names and their values in rows found?

Comment: In Oracle, table DUAL contains only one row :) But yes, if table you're selecting from contains million rows, you'd get million rows of "Tag1, English and DummyData". Regardless of how many columns that table actually has.

Comment: Ah I see now this is an auxiliary table inteded to perform this kind of 'tricks' ! Thank you for this remark!

Answer (score 2):

In SQL, the single quote is used to define string and date constant values (which in the documentation are called "literal values").  In this case, your query returns three columns, each a string.

You are, of course, free to write your code however you like.  I recommend always using `as` for column aliases:

```
SELECT 'Tag1' as FIELD_ONE, 'English' as FIELD_TWO, 'DummyData' as FIELD_THREE 
FROM SOME_TABLE;
```

This makes it much easier to debug errors if you leave out a comma.